# angular-i18n select syntax in attribute

Tags: javascript, angular, internationalization, angular-i18n

I was trying to use the i18n SELECT syntax to translate a placeholder for an input field:

```
<input placeholder="{userRole, admin{you are an admin} other {you are a user}}" i18n-placeholder="MYAPP.PLACEHOLDER|my placeholder">
```

this results to the following xlf file entry:

```
<trans-unit id="85f60a0a03b3b4e189252fc0157dd403e806bbcc" datatype="html">
    <source>{userRole, admin{you are an admin} other {you are a user}}</source>
    <context-group purpose="location">
      <context context-type="sourcefile">path/to/my/file.component.ts</context>
      <context context-type="linenumber">4</context>
    </context-group>
    <note priority="1" from="description">my placeholder</note>
    <note priority="1" from="meaning">MYAPP.PLACEHOLDER</note>
  </trans-unit>
```

So it seems like the SELECT syntax isn't recognized. When i use the syntax not to translate an attribute but the content of an element the .xlf  tag looks like this:

```
<source>{VAR_SELECT, admin{you are an admin} other {you are a user}}</source>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like this an allready known issue with Angular

> Allow ICU messages in attributes [blocked, requires an update of the pars

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16477

A workaround for this is to use a different tag to implement the translation:

```
<span i18n='SOME_TITLE|Description Text' #translatedPlaceholder>{VAR_SELECT, admin{you are an admin} other {you are a user}}</span>    
<input [placeholder]="translatedPlaceholder.textContent" />
```