# Angular i18n binding

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

How would I achieve translating a binding using Angular built-in i18n?

```
    //this works fine
    <mycomponent i18n-myattribute myattribute="just an attribute"></mycomponent>

    //but what if it's a binding???
    <mycomponent [myattribute]="myVar"></mycomponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48567086/2582581

Apparently using ICU expression are not supported in attributes yet, [it's under development](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/3506).